# Not getting proper output in magento product page

Tags: php, magento, video, product

I'm trying to add videos on product page with images in the same place like after 4 images it must show video. Person who wants to see video of product can click of video and see the video. To add this feature i have created a new attribute called product video as text field and written some code to extend media.phtml. I have tried adding the code in media.phtml but not getting any change in the output.Now i have tried writing the same code in new phmtl file called video.phtml but where to call that video.phtml file, not getting the exact result m looking for.
Links shown below are for files:-

media.phtml

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By64gw5ORtRjdXJfRGhHLUVJelk/view?usp=sharing

video.phtml

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By64gw5ORtRjbGtaMWh5NC01ZEU/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: 'Not getting proper output', what is the outpout that you get and what do you expect?

Comment: no change is happening but i want 4 product images and 5th as video on product page of Magento.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are editing the **media.phtml** file in your current theme.
Also in the media.phtml you shared in drive, I could not see any code related to video.

If you want to use your **video.phtml**, add a new block in the layout file **catalog.xml** in your theme.

You should your block inside the handle **catalog_product_view**. You may add it just after the media block. Like this:

```
<block type="core/template" name="product.info.video" as="video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml"/> <!--your video block -->
```

Then inside view.phtml of your product, add this:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml("video");
```

I have written a similar module for video, you may look at this code and build your own.

[Video Gallery for Vzaar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/22572/s/video-hosting-and-product-gallery-with-vzaar-1/)

Comment: Thank you for reply hashid. i have tried video.phtml option but it is not working don't know nothing is showing in product page of my website i have added block to catalog.xml and added code in view.phtml but still you can see the output on qubitinformationsystems.com/yoga/d-muse-women-coral-pink-top-37.html

Comment: I assume you are editing in the wrong place. Could you write a die("STOP THERE"); in your phtml and check if its working ?

Comment: die() is not being used in php i think? and u want me to add where?

Comment: Extension doesn't work with 1.9, so be careful. Otherwise this answer is right...

Comment: Please enable template path hints to know which template is active. You might be editing at wrong place. Also if product page is coming blank, there might be a fatal error. Check you error log.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code :

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And also you need  add the video file in app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Use the below code for adding a video.phtml file then it will display the video in product detail page:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('templateFolderName/video.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```